MYSQL Entity diagram
please share entity diagram for the default core drupal tables and the respective primary and foreign key mappings with other tables.
Example:
Need to see the relationship between these tables
1.key_value
2.sessions
3.users_field_data
4.locales_location
5.locales_source
6.search_api_item
7.locales_target
I need for Drupal 9.5.7 like this https://www.drupal.org/node/2360815 as follows


You can install phpmyadmin and access the "Designer" tab in top menu after selection of the database.
